# cancel storekit in app purchase if DB upload fails

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I have a game that I am building and this game allows users to purchase points (in-app consumable product). In the case they do, I have to call a function to update a field in my database to reflect this point change. But how can I error handle or even reverse/cancel a store kit transaction if my database upload fails? Apple allows users to use Apple Pay when WiFi is off and if WiFi is off then the database upload will fail. I want to figure out a way to modify the points in the database after the transaction was verified but also only charge the user if the database upload is successful. I'd appreciate any help.

Store kit file:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

public enum StoreError: Error {
    case failedVerification
}

class StoreKitManager: ObservableObject {
    private let userService = UserService()
    @Published var storeProducts: [Product] = []
    var updateListenerTask: Task<Void, Error>? = nil
    private var productDict: [String] = {
        var keys: [String] = []
        for i in stride(from: 10, through: 900, by: 10) {
            keys.append("\(i)ELO")
        }
        keys.append("OneDay")
        keys.append("ThreeDay")
        return keys
    }()

    init() {
        updateListenerTask = listenForTransactions()
        Task {
            await requestProducts()
        }
    }
    deinit {  //denit transaction listener on exit or app close
        updateListenerTask?.cancel()
    }
    func listenForTransactions() -> Task<Void, Error> {
        return Task.detached {
            for await result in Transaction.updates {
                do {
                    let transaction = try self.checkVerified(result)
                    
                    self.updateDB(transaction: transaction)
                    
                    await transaction.finish()
                } catch {
                    print("Failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @MainActor
    func requestProducts() async {
        do {
            storeProducts = try await Product.products(for: productDict)
        } catch {
            print("Failed - error retrieving products \(error)")
        }
    }
    func checkVerified<T>(_ result: VerificationResult<T>) throws -> T {
        switch result {
        case .unverified:
            throw StoreError.failedVerification
        case .verified(let signedType):
            return signedType
        }
    }
    func updateDB(transaction: Transaction) {
        if let amount = Int(transaction.productID.dropLast(3)){
            userService.editElo(withUid: nil, withAmount: amount) { }
        }
    }
    func purchase(_ product: Product) async throws -> Bool {
        let result = try await product.purchase()

        switch result {
        case .success(let verificationResult):
            let transaction = try checkVerified(verificationResult)
            
            updateDB(transaction: transaction)
            
            await transaction.finish()
            
            return true
        case .userCancelled, .pending:
            return false
        default:
            return false
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: First, ApplePay is different to Apple In-App-Purchase.  ApplePay is for credit-card payments at a payment terminal.  You can't complete an in-app-purchase without network connectivity. Second, you can't cancel an IAP.  What you do is not finalise it until you have updated your server successfully.  The transaction remains on the queue in a pending state until you mark it complete.  This is why it is very important that one of the first things your app does on launch is instantiate the transaction queue observer.

Comment: @paulw11 thanks, im assuming the line “await transaction.finish()” is the one responsible for finalizing the purchase? And I should wait till the database is successfully updated before calling this line

Comment: Probably. You seem to be using some sort of wrapper around StoreKit. If your minimum deployment target supports it, consider using StoreKit2 directly. It is much easier to use

Comment: @Paulw11 I thought this was storekit2, would you possibly know a good tutorial or example I can follow

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake, it is storekit2 